# Java Custom Google Analytics 4 Server-Side Event User-IP

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In my current Java project, it's easy to track server-side user events in the "old" Google Analytics Universal Project with simple REST calls to Google Analytics. So that location tracking was working, i could override the server ip with the user ip, according to the parameter "&uip=1.2.3.4" (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=de#uip).

As upgrading to GA4 is recommended, I was able to change all the REST parameters in my project and show my events in the new dashboard, except for the user location. I can't find any information about such a parameter. I tried using still "uip" but now all my requests are located to the country of my server.

Unfortunately it's not possible to track the event client side, because my project is a simple REST API, returning only JSON data.

Does anyone have an idea, if there's such a parameter like "uip" for ga4 or if this isn't possible anymore?

In the following way I setup my parameters:

```
private String getQueryParameters(MeasurementEvent event) {
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
    body.append("?v=").append(version);
    body.append("&tid=").append(trackingId);
    body.append("&cid=").append(event.getClientId());
    body.append("&en=").append(eventName);
    body.append("&aip=1");

    if (StringUtils.hasText(event.getAction())) {
        body.append("&ep.useraction=").append(event.getAction());
    }
    if (StringUtils.hasText(event.getCategory())) {
        body.append("&ep.awsregion=").append(event.getCategory());
    }
    if (StringUtils.hasText(event.getLabel())) {
        body.append("&ep.softwarename=").append(event.getLabel());
    }
    if (StringUtils.hasText(event.getRemoteAddress())) {
        body.append("&uip=").append(event.getRemoteAddress());
    }
    if (StringUtils.hasText(event.getUrl())) {
        body.append("&dl=").append(event.getUrl());
    }
    return body.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @MohammadNikravan Unfortunately not. As a result I kept going with the Universal Project and did not upgrade to GA4.